# Spring Data Solr: Retrieve document when using an explicit composite id as a routing key

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

I have a composite id which is a String consisting of the tenant and id of an entity separated by a "!" (for example say "tenant!id").

I am sending this composite Id as input to the query method findOne(ID compositeId), but at the time of execution the BasePredicateProcessor in the QueryParserBase class is converting "!" to "\!", which breaks the routing key sent to Solr. Solr is therefor unable to retrieve the entity  using the crudrepository.findOne() method.

Is there any way to avoid the conversion of "!" to "\!", or is there an alternate way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the total answer, but suggestions about possible approaches.

I don't know the specifics, but you can change what gets used to parse the incoming query to something else (probably solrconfig.xml).  I don't know which of the available "processors" would do what you want however - or if one is even available with that kind of specific behavior, since I assume you will still want the other "benefits" provided by the BasePredicateProcessor.  See next possibility...

An alternative would be to extend BasePredicateProcessor and use your extended class (again, probably solrconfig.xml)  Your modified code would leave the "!" alone.  This second option will require coding.

Third option is to see if there's an "escape sequence" you could use to modify the query string before you send it in to Solr...  Something like an "escape the escape".  I don't know if that's possible. It's worth investigating however.

Some *possibly* useful links for #3

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-do-you-query-for-a-string-containing-a-colon-td481672.html

https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

From the second link:

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

- - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

\(1\+1\):2